# R: transform coordinate system of SpatialPolygon that crosses longitude (-)180

Tags: r, coordinate-transformation, r-sp

I have created polygons with CRS = UTM (see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294317/r-raster-extract-weighted-mean-within-circle-of-specific-radius)), which I need to transform to latitude/longitude. Some of my polygons cross the dateline, which causes the transformation to create a polygon that crosses the entire globe.

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)

points <- data.frame(x = c(-179.5, 0), y = c(-50, -30))
coordinates(points) <- ~x+y
proj4string(points) <- '+init=epsg:4326'

points_sp <- spTransform(points, CRS('+init=epsg:32621')) # wrong zone, but ignored for example
# expand point to circle
circles <- gBuffer(points_sp, width = 1e+5)
# transform back to WGS84
circles_latlon <- spTransform(circles, CRS(proj4string(points)))

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(circles, axes = TRUE, main = 'UTM')
plot(circles_latlon, axes = TRUE, main = 'WGS84')
```

[image]

Is there a solution to split the polygons? Or and alternative solution that takes care of the dateline issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just found this question after having asked a similar one. There it was [suggested to me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55164190/6360050) by @Humpelstielzchen to use `st_wrap_dateline()` from the `sf`-package, which seems to work as expected so far.