# Is there a better way for handling SpatialPolygons that cross the antimeridian (date line)?

Tags: r, polygon, geos, r-maptools, dismo

### TL;DR

What is the best way in R to handle SpatialPolygons intersecting/overlapping the anti meridian at +/-180° of latitude and cut them into two sections along that meridian?

### Preface

This is going to be a long one, but only because I'm going to include a lot of code and figures for illustration. I'll show you what my goal is and how I normally achieve that and then demonstrate how it all breaks together in a literal edge case. As the title suggests, I already found one possible solution to my problem, so I'll include that too. But it is not 100% clean and I'd like to see if somebody can come up with something more elegant. In any case I think this is an interesting problem, as only a couple of days ago I wouldn't have have suspected in my wildest dreams that this could even be an issue in 2019.

### Regular work flow in R

First, create an example data set that works

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(dismo)
library(maptools) # this is just for plotting a simple world map in the background
data("wrld_simpl")


# create a set of locations
locations <- SpatialPoints(coords=cbind(c(50,0,0,0), c(10, 30, 50, 70)), proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
plot(wrld_simpl, border="grey50")
points(locations, pch=19, col="blue")
```

Looks like this:
[image: locations on a world map]
Then, I use circles() from the dismo package to create circular buffers around those locations. I use this function, because it takes into account that the Earth is not flat:

```
buffr <- circles(p = locations, d = 1500000, lonlat=TRUE, dissolve=FALSE)
plot(wrld_simpl, border="grey50")
plot(buffr, add=TRUE, border="red", lwd=2)
points(locations, pch=19, col="blue")
```

That looks like this:
[image: locations with their individual buffers]

Then, merge the single buffers into one big (multi-) polygon:

```
buffr <- buffr@polygons # extract the SpatialPolygons object from the "CirclesRange" object
buffr <- gUnaryUnion(buffr) # merge

plot(wrld_simpl, border="grey50")
plot(buffr, add=TRUE, border="red", lwd=2)
points(locations, pch=19, col="blue")
```

This is exactly what I need:
[image: points with merged buffers]

### The problem

Now observe what happens when we introduce locations that so are close to the anti-meridian (+/-180° of longitude) that the buffer has to cross that line:

```
locations <- SpatialPoints(coords=cbind(c(50,0,0,0, 175, -170), c(10, 30, 50, 70,0,-10)), proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
buffr <- circles(p = locations, d = 1500000, lonlat=TRUE, dissolve=FALSE)

plot(wrld_simpl, border="grey50")
plot(buffr, add=TRUE, border="red", lwd=2)
points(locations, pch=19, col="blue")
```

The circles() command does manage to create polygon segments on the other side of the antimeridian (if dissolve=FALSE):

[image]

but the polygon crosses the entire globe instead of wrapping around properly (intersecting with 0° instead of 180°). That leads to self-intersections and

```
buffr <- gUnaryUnion(buffr@polygons)
```

will fail with

> Error in gUnaryUnion(buffr@polygons) :    TopologyException: Input
>   geom 0 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point
>   170.08604674698876 12.562175561621103 at 170.08604674698876 12.562175561621103

### The quick and slightly dirty solution

First, we need to detect whether a polygon crosses the anti meridian. However, none of them actually intersects +/-180°. Instead, I'm using two pseudo anti meridians that lie close to the real one, but far enough to the east and west to probably intersect the polygons in question. If a polygon intersects both of them, it must also cross the anti meridian.

```
antimeridian <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(slinelist=list(Line(coords=cbind(c(179,179), c(90,-90)))), ID="1"),
              Lines(slinelist=list(Line(coords=cbind(c(-179,-179), c(90,-90)))), ID="2")),
                                   proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
intrscts <- gIntersects(antimeridian, buffr, byid = TRUE)
any(intrscts[,1] & intrscts[,2])
intrscts <- which(intrscts[,1] & intrscts[,2])
buffr.bad <- buffr[intrscts,]
buffr.good <- buffr[-intrscts,]

plot(wrld_simpl)
plot(buffr.good, border="blue", add=TRUE)
plot(buffr.bad, border="red", add=TRUE)
```

After having detected and separated the "bad" polygons I simply split them into two separate sections by looking at the longitudinal coordinates. Every coordinate pair that has a negative value there goes into the new western polygon, positive ones into the eastern one. Then I just merge it all back together, do my gUnaryUnion and have pretty much what I need:

```
buffr.fixed <- buffr.good
for(i in 1:length(buffr.bad)){
  thispoly <- buffr.bad[i,]                              # select first problematic polygon
  crds <- thispoly@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords   # extract coordinates
  crds.west <- subset(crds, crds[,1] < 0)               # western half of the polygon
  crds.east<- subset(crds, crds[,1] > 0)
  # turn into Spatial*, merge back together, re-add original crs
  sppol.east <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(crds.east)), paste0("east_", i))))
  sppol.west <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(crds.west)), paste0("west_", i))))
  sppol <- spRbind(sppol.east, sppol.west)
  proj4string(sppol) <- proj4string(thispoly)

  buffr.fixed <- spRbind(buffr.fixed, sppol)
}
buffr.final <- gUnaryUnion(buffr.fixed)
plot(wrld_simpl, border="grey50")
points(locations, pch=19, col="blue")
plot(buffr.final, add=TRUE, border="red", lwd=2)
```

The final outcome:
[image: merged buffers, problem solved?]

### The actual question

So, this solution works for me for my current use case, but it has some issues:

- It will probably break completely as soon as one of the buffers crosses both the anti- and the prime-meridian (which is not so unlikely if the original point locations lie close to the poles).
- it is not quite exact, as the two polygon sections are not cut at +/-180° but at the highest negative/positive values of latitude that were present in the original polygon.
- I find it hard to believe that there is no "proper" way of doing this.

So the question all this boils down to is: **Is there a better way of doing this**?

While I was trying to figure this out, I came across the [`nowrapRecenter()` and `nowrapSpatialPolygons()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/maptools/man/nowrapRecenter.html) functions from the `maptools` package, which at first sight looked like they do exactly what I want. Upon closer inspection, they are aimed at pretty much the opposite use case (centering a map on the anti meridian and thus cutting polygons along the prime meridian). I played around with them, but failed to make them work for me – in fact, they only managed to make things worse.

Thanks for you attention!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, it's the current year and there is a solution for your problem. The `sf`-package has the function `st_wrap_dateline()`, which is exactly what you need.

```
library(dismo)
library(sf)


locations <- SpatialPoints(coords=cbind(c(50,0,0,0, 175, -170), c(10, 30, 50, 70,0,-10)), proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
buffr <- circles(p = locations, d = 1500000, lonlat=TRUE, dissolve=FALSE)

buffr2 <- as(buffr@polygons, Class = "sf") %>%
            st_wrap_dateline(options = c("WRAPDATELINE=YES")) %>%
             st_union()


plot(wrld_simpl, border="grey50")
plot(buffr2, add=TRUE, border="red", lwd=2)
points(locations, pch=19, col="blue")
```

`st_wrap_dateline` converts the polygons which cross the international date line, or "antimeridian", into `MULTIPOLYGON`. And that's about it.

Does that solve your problem? At least it shortens the way quite a bit, to get where you are now. ^^

[image]

Comment: Bingo! I can convert that to an old-fashioned SpatialPolygons via `as_Spatial(buffr2)` and carry on from there. Only issue is that I may have to update some PCs that are running older versions of R. Anyway, that's pretty much exactly what I was looking for, so many thanks for that!